# how to count the values(any string,integer,mixture of both) of single column but if there is any repeat entry it should not be counted?

Tags: django, excel

Here i'm using this formula `COUNTA(A5:A65536)`. It's working but it's counting repeated entries.

```
sheetname.write(2, 0, Formula("COUNTA(A5:A65536)"))
```

I want the number of count in A2 cell

My excel sheet column:

```
Total number of entries
3
Number of entries
21w3331
21w3332
21w3332
```

Here the total no of entries should be `2` as `21w3332` is repeated but I'm getting Total number of entries `3`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A4,A2:A4))
```

where, `A2:A4` is range containing data.

If your range may have blank cells then use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A65536&""))
```

Comment: #DIV/0!
GIVING THIS ERROR

Comment: @user8471925 - Use `=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A65536&""))`

Comment: giving xlwt.ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException: can't parse formula SUMPRODUCT((A5:A20004<>)/COUNTIF(A5:A20004,A5:A20004&))

Comment: again #DIV/0! GIVING THIS ERROR

Comment: @user8471925 - Could you share the screen shot with formula used.

Comment: if i enter in excel ctrl+alt+enter it is working...but it is initially giving divide y 0 error

Comment: sheet.write(2, 0, Formula('SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/(COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A65536&"")))'))  using this formula....

Comment: @user8471925 - When you'll copy the formula from your comment mentioned above into the excel, there are two spaces between last set of `A5:A6‌​5536` i.e. `SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/(COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A6 HERE ‌​5536&"")))`, kindly check and remove those spaces.

Comment: there is no space in my codesheet.write(2, 0, Formula('SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A6‌​5536&""))'))

Comment: @user8471925 - Try this formula directly in excel sheet and check if it gives your desired result or not.

Comment: @user8471925 - FYI, your above comment have 4 spaces this time when copied to excel.

Comment: when pasted directly in excel it works..but i want it to work  from the code

Comment: @user8471925 - May be try `codesheet.write(2, 0, '=SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A65536&""))')`

Comment: 'INDEX(SUMPRODUCT((A5:A65536<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A65536,A5:A65536&"")),0)' i have tried this to avoid entering cnrt+shft+enter..still its giving div by 0 error

Answer (score 0):

Try `=SUM(1/COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:" & ADDRESS(MATCH(2,1/(A2:A65536<>"")),1)), INDIRECT("A2:" & ADDRESS(MATCH(2,1/(A2:A65536<>"")),1))))`

This is an array formula which you must confirm with Ctl + Shift + Enter. When correctly confirmed it will be displayed between curly braces in the formula bar.

Comment: It works - sort of :-). The formula requires that last row of the range to be not blank. Therefore I have now amended the formula to replace hard-coded row 65536 with the last row in column A that isn't blank.